# Unix deleting files

Tags: unix, delete-file

How can I delete ordered numeric folders in Unix? For example, I want to delete folders from 5600 till 6500. However, I do not want to delete for example the folder 599 (which is inside those numbers because they are actually ordered alphabetically).

Any ideas?

Comment: Unix doesn't have folders.  It has directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `?` as a single-character wildcard. So this might work:

```
rm -rf 5[6-9]?? 6[0-4]?? 6500
```

As always, it's a good idea to use `echo` first to make sure your wildcard matches the right set of names:

```
echo 5[6-9]?? 6[0-4]?? 6500
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `seq` to operate on ranges, for instance:

```
for num in $(seq 5600 6500); do rm -r $num; done
```